# How to add a wrapper class to a simple_form custom collection radio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I've created a SimpleForm custom input and also want to add a class name to a certain item's wrapper element based on its value in order to decorate the item by CSS. But I can't figure out how I can access to each item's value. Please refer my code below:

```
class ProductOptionInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionRadioButtonsInput
    def input
        label_method, value_method = detect_collection_methods

        @builder.send("collection_radio_buttons",
                    attribute_name, collection, value_method, label_method,
                    input_options, input_html_options, &collection_block_for_nested_boolean_style
        )
    end

    def build_nested_boolean_style_item_tag(collection_builder)
        template.shirt_option_icon(attribute_name, collection_builder.value) + \
        collection_builder.radio_button + \
        template.content_tag(:div, collection_builder.text, class: :name)
    end

    def item_wrapper_class
        classes = super
        classes << ' highlight' if @builder.object.product.send(attribute_name) == [current item's value]
        classes
    end
end
```